# How do I rewrite URLs with Nginx admin / Apache / Wordpress

Tags: apache, wordpress, url-rewriting, nginx

I have the following URL format:

```
www.example.com/members/admin/projects/?projectid=41
```

And I would like to rewrite them to the following format:

```
www.example.com/avits/projectname/
```

Project names do not have to be unique when a user creates them therefore I will be checking for an existing name and appending an integer to the end of the project name if a project of the same name already exists. e.g. example.project, example.project1, example.project2 etc.

I am happy setting up the GET request to query the database by project name however I am having huge problems setting up these pretty url's.

I am using Apache with Nginx Admin installed which mens that all static content is served via Nginx without the overhead of apache.

I am totally confused as to whether I should be employing an nginx rewrite rule in my nginx.conf file or standard rewrites in my .htaccess file.

To confuse matters further although this is a rather large custom appliction it is build on top of a wordpress backbone for easy blogging functionality meaning that I also have the built in wordpress rewrite module at my disposal.

I have tried all three methods with absolutely no success.  I have read a lot on the matter but simply cannot seem to get anything to work.  I am certain this is purely down to a complete lack of understanding on with regards to URL rewriting.  Combined with the fact that I don't know which type of rewriting should be applicable in my case means that I am doing nothing more than going round in circles.

Can anyone clear up this matter for me and explain how to rewrite my URLs in the manner described above?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are proxying all the non static file requests to Apache, do the rewrites there - you don't need to do anything on nginx as it will just pass the requests to the back end.

The problem with what you are proposing is that it's not actually a rewrite, a rewrite is taking the first URL and just changing it around or moving the user to another location.

What you need actually takes logic to extrapolate the project name from the project ID.

For example you can rewrite:

```
www.example.com/members/admin/projects/?projectid=41
```

To:

```
www.example.com/avits/41/
```

Fairly easily, but can you map that /41/ in your app code to change it to /projectname/ - because a URL rewrite can't do that.

Comment: Thanks Gareth,  The logic you are describing is actually in place and is not an issue.  It is purely the rewriting itself that I am struggling with.

Comment: So you want to make the exact rewrite about? Try something like this:

    So you want to make the exact rewrite above in my example? Do something like this:

`rewrite  ^/members/admin/projects/?projectid=$  /avits/$1?/  last;`